# .NET Max Memory Use 2GB even for x64 Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

I've read (http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx) that the maximum size of an object in .NET is 2 GB.

Am I correct in assuming that if I have an Object that takes up 256 MB Memory, since it is a reference type, I can have an array of these 256 MB Objects where all the objects together may takeup >2GB Memory as long as the size of the reference array stays below 2 GB?

Comment: Interesting question. I didn't know there would be this limit on a 64 bit machine. That said I can't think of many scenarios for an app that holds 2GB in one object!

Comment: I agree, there are not many scenarios where you would need more than 2 GB in a single object. A game server or database server is really the only thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

The 2GB limit applies to each object individually. The total memory used for all objects can exceed 2GB.

(Whether the runtime is able to allocate enough memory for your requirements is another matter. I doubt if it could find a full 2GB of spare memory on a 32bit machine, but it shouldn't be a problem on 64bit.)

Comment: So the "reference array" will be an object that would (typically) take up the same amount of space as an "integer array"?

Comment: Nate > it is an implementation detail but references are currently pointers and so they have the same size as the pointer size (In C it was the same as the sizeof(int) on most systems but in C# int always mean Int32)

Comment: This is bizarre considering that .NET's Array class has special methods that take "long" array length arguments. If the limit is 2GB then it is impossible for an array length to overflow a 32-bit int.

Comment: @Qwertie: If i did the math right, 2GB of Int32 objects in an array should take 549,755,813,888 indices, which is indeed out of the range for an Int32. Make that an array of bytes, and it's 4x bigger.

Comment: @Qwertie: The Array members that take or return Int64 just cast those values to Int32 internally and, in the case of parameters, will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if a long parameter isn't between int.MinValue and int.MaxValue.

Comment: @Will:  (I realize this is 3 years old, but 3 people upvoted your incorrect comment) No, you didn't do the math right, because a 4 GB limit comes from uniquely identifying each "1 byte integer" using a 32 bit integer.  If you want to uniquely index each "4 byte integer", you could address 4 X 4 GB = 16 GB with a 32 bit index.  In practice, those indexes are signed values, so you only have 31 bits, so you have to cut that number in half.

Answer (score 6):

"In .NET 4 and earlier, no object could be larger than 2GB in size, even in 64-bit processes.  For certain workloads that use large arrays, however, this size limit can be constraining.  As such, .NET 4.5 supports lifting the limit for arrays in 64-bit processes, such that arrays may be larger than 2GB.  This means, for example, that you could allocate an array of Int32.MaxValue Int32s, even though such an array will consume 8GB.  Large objects in .NET are allocated on a special heap, known not coincidentally as the Large Object Heap (LOH);  .NET 4.5 has also seen significant performance improvements to the LOH, including usage of better algorithms for managing free memory in the heap."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=VS.110).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2012/05/16/net-improvements-for-cloud-and-server-applications.aspx