# Hashtable - out of memory

Tags: c#, memory, hashtable

I am using Hashtable in my c# application. I am loading millions of key into, but after the application exceed the 3,7GB of RAM it gives me an "out of memory" exception.

I use x64 operation system, and the computer has 16GB of ram. I was thinking about maybe this could be an x86 limitation. I changed the build type to x64 but I still get the error.

Is there a maximum memory size for an object in .net? Can I do something to use all the memory?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: For a data set of this size you might want to use some disk-based (or partially disk-based) solution. It's not good karma to load that much data into the memory. Have a look at BerkeleyDB, it has .NET bindings and it's free.

Comment: RAM is irrelevant; *RAM is simply a cache to make memory access faster*.  The relevant scarce resource is the *available address space*.

Comment: Eric Lippert: I don't know if you commented on the question or my comment but what I meant that (besides the limited address space) it takes an awful lot of time to load that much data from the disk (especially since/if it's getting paged out).

Comment: Right; what I'm getting at is that a question which begins "I'm running out of memory but I have plenty of RAM" demonstrates a misunderstanding of what actually is being run out of.  You can have 256 megs of RAM and still have twenty programs each using 500 megs of address space; the machine will be slow, but you won't run out of address space. And you can have 14 GB of empty RAM and still run out of address space.  Amount of RAM is completely irrelevant to the question of running out of address space; it's only relevant to performance.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look on this previous answer: [.NET Max Memory Use 2GB even for x64 Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982051/net-max-memory-use-2gb-even-for-x64-assemblies)

> The 2GB limit applies to each object individually. The total memory used for all objects can exceed 2GB.

Comment: +1, beat me while I was still typing. See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: @Sapph, ty for that link, I was looking for it to complement this answer =)

Answer (score 7):

Use a `Dictionary<,>` instead of `HashTable`. In a `HashTable` both the key and value are objects, so if they are value types they will be boxed. A `Dictionary` can have value types as key and/or value, which uses less memory. If you for example use an `int` as key, each will use 28 bytes in a `HashTable` while they only use 4 bytes in a `Dictionary`.

If both the key and value are value types and use less than 8 bytes the `Dictionary` will be able to hold more items than the `HashTable`.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=592) states that .NET limits the size of a single object to two gigabyte.

Answer (score 1):

I found this page really useful as I was having exactly the same problem in VB .net. I had created some very large hashtables and my application was throwing an out of memory exception when trying to create them.

I tried "Guffa's" idea of using a Dictionary on a smaller example hashtable and the resulting dictionary actually increased in size!

His suggestion got me thinking about what I was actually writing to the Hashtable. So I looked at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28VS.90%29.aspx) and decided I did not really need to be storing data of type **Long**, an **Integer** was more than sufficient.  I know I'm probably telling all you gurus out there what is blindingly obvious but I was able to reduce the resulting serialized hastables (12 of them in total) from 81.9Mb to 69.4Mb simply by declaring the variables as integers instead of Longs.

This did not actually resolve my problem but will certainly improve the time taken to load them back into memory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the amount of physical RAM in your system, or whether is x64 compiled or not. Nor is it now true that .NET must limit objects to 2GB. (You may want to investigate .NET 4.5's Large Object Heap for more information on this.) The reason you are getting "Out of memory" is because the process cannot map a contiguous section of memory in the size you requested.

Eric Lippert has an excellent [blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/) on this very topic, and I notice that he commented on this question, but unfortunately did not answer it.

So here's the answer: **accept the fact that the memory size you seek with this implementation is not readily available, and solve your problem by breaking it down into smaller memory chunks.**

I had this same problem and had to take the same approach. Working with jagged arrays may help, or breaking your data into multiple logical components and create a series of smaller HashTables.